# Rails using wrong custom named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, namespaces

I am building a blog post versioning system where a user can do the following actions:

1. Change a Draft Post to a Published Post
2. Archive a Published
3. Republish and Archived Post

The status of the Post is set in a column of the Post & the status can be "Draft", "Active", "Archive"
Right now, whenever I hit "publish" or "republish" it marks the page as "archived."

PostsController.rb

```
def mark_published
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.update(status: 'active')
  @post.save
  redirect_to confirmation_admin_post_path(@post.id), notice: 'post has been Published.'
end

 def mark_archived
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.status = 'archived'
    @post.save
    redirect_to confirmation_admin_post_path(id: @post.id), notice: 'post has been archived.'
 end
```

show.html.slim

```
 .col-sm-6.col-md-2.col-lg-2
   = link_to 'PUBLISH ', mark_published_admin_post_path(@post), class: 'btn btn-success btn-block mb15 btn-lg '
 .col-sm-6.col-md-2.col-lg-2
   = link_to 'ARCHIVE ', mark_archived_admin_post_path(@post), class: 'btn btn-success btn-block mb15 btn-lg
```

'

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts do
      member do
       get 'posts',  to: 'posts#mark_archived', as: :mark_archived
       get 'posts',  to: 'posts#mark_published', as: :mark_published
       get 'posts',  to: 'posts#confirmation', as: :confirmation
    end 
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

```
mark_archived_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/posts(.:format)                admin/posts#mark_archived
 mark_published_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/posts(.:format)                admin/posts#mark_published
 mark_archived_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/posts(.:format)                admin/posts#mark_archived
 confirmation_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/posts/confirmation(.:format)     admin/posts#confirmation
```

Comment: What does the confirmation route do?

Comment: Your routes.rb file seems to be incorrect. If you do `rake routes` you'll be able to see all the generated routes.

Comment: The confirmation route show a confirmation of the action that just happened.  i.e. "Your page has been archived...."

Comment: I've just posted my rake routes.  They match my paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output of `rake routes` shows, your `routes.rb` file appears to be incorrect. This way you're creating 3 routes with different names and going to different controller actions but the same path i.e. a GET to /admin/posts/:id/posts. Try changing your file to something like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts do
    member do
      post 'mark_archived',  to: 'posts#mark_archived', as: :mark_archived
      post 'mark_published',  to: 'posts#mark_published', as: :mark_published
      post 'confirmation',  to: 'posts#confirmation', as: :confirmation
    end 
  end
end
```

The `post` vs `get` doesn't matter that much. What matters is that they're not all `get 'posts'`.